# Kivy, calling a dropdown list when a button is submitted

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to create a dropdown list that is called when a button is submitted. After the drop down list is called i want the value of the button to be set to the button in the dropdown list that has been selected. I then want to retrieve this value back in my code to carry out some logic. I found this question that has been previously asked and it outlines exactly what i would like to achieve [Python, Kivy. Get text from dynamically created buttons with a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50759993/python-kivy-get-text-from-dynamically-created-buttons-with-a-dropdown). However, i tried incorporating the answer in my code but for some reason the drop down list does not appear. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out and tell me what is it i am doing in correctly.

**Scrap.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
import datetime as dt

Window.size = (800,600)

class CustomDropDown(DropDown):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_buttons()

    def add_buttons(self):
        for index in range(10):

            btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)

            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.select(btn.text))

            self.add_widget(btn)

class MainWindow(Screen):

    check_solid = ObjectProperty(False)
    check_water = ObjectProperty(False)
    check_boiling = ObjectProperty(False)
    s_id = str(dt.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d%H%M"))

    def btn(self):

        print(self.check_solid.state)
        print(self.check_water.state)
        print(self.check_boiling.state)

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def Run_Draws_Test(self, value):
        print(value)

class Checkbox(CheckBox):
    pass


class ScrapApp(App):
    title = "Chemistry Sample Requests"

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrapApp().run()
```

**scrap.kv**

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Button>:
    size_hint: 0.1,0.1

<Label>:
    size_hint: 0.1,0.1

<Checkbox>:
    size_hint: 0.1,0.1

<TextInput>:
    size_hint: 0.2,0.1
    multiline: False

<CustomDropDown>:
    on_select:
        app.root.ids.MainWindow.ids.mainbutton.text = '{}'.format(args[1])
        app.root.Run_Draws_Test(args[1])

<MainWindow>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    check_solid: solid_check
    check_boiling: boiling_check
    check_water: water_check

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text: "Sample ID: "
            pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "top":0.95}

        Label:
            text: root.s_id
            pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top": 0.95}

        Label:
            text: "Plant ID: "
            pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "top": 0.8}

        Button:
            id: mainbutton
            text: "Choose"
            pos: 400,400
            size_hint: None,None
            size: 150, 50
            on_release: Factory.CustomDropDown().open(self)

        Label:
            text: "Formulation: "
            pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "top": 0.65}

        TextInput:
            id: id_formulation
            pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top": 0.65}

        Label:
            text: "Solids Test: "
            pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "top": 0.5}

        Checkbox:
            id: solid_check
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "top": 0.5}

        Label:
            text: "Water Content Test: "
            pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "top": 0.35}

        Checkbox:
            id: water_check
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "top": 0.35}

        Label:
            text: "Boiling Point: "
            pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "top": 0.2}

        Checkbox:
            id: boiling_check
            pos_hint: {"x":0.25, "top": 0.2}

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.7, "top": 0.5}
            on_release: root.btn()

<MyScreenManager>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0,0
            size: 800, 600
    MainWindow:
        id: MainWindow
        name: 'MainWindow'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into bugs like this before. I don't know if Kivy is working as intended with this or how to fix it. Anyone with more knowledge than me, I'd be glad to hear the reasoning to this.

```
class CustomDropDown(DropDown):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_buttons()

    def add_buttons(self):
        for index in range(10):

            #btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
            btn = Button(text='Value %d' % index)
            btn.size_hint_y = None
            btn.height = 44


            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.select(btn.text))

            self.add_widget(btn)
```

These kind of things cause me nothing but frustration.

Comment: ahh tell me about it! It makes me really frustrated as i end up on something like this for hours!

Comment: I actually managed to get it to work but i still dont understand why. See my edit in my question

Comment: I just noticed that you over ride the standard hints for Buttons. I don't know how I didn't see that before. It might have been that.

Comment: ahhh! It did work, sorry i didn't realize that you removed the size_hint and height from btn. Where exactly was i overriding the size_hint for the buttons? Could you please outline?? @cabboose

Comment: Oh my i get it now. I was overriding the size_hint_y that i already set out in the kivy file under <Button>: ! Thank you for outlining that! really appreciated!